# Trouble with WordPress's add_menu_page function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having an issue with **add_menu_page()**. My Page output is not showing, where it should be I am getting an error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in
>   /home/content/45/8909445/html/clients/ereading/wp-includes/plugin.php
>   on line 470

I know **add_action()** uses PHP's native **call_user_func_array()** so I guess that might have something to do with it. Below is my code for creating the menu page and the page output function (Currently I just wanted to echo some text):

```
public static function register_wpidSwiper_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page('iDangerous Swiper Slides', 'Homepage Slides', 'manage_options',
           'wp_idangerous_swiper', array( $this, 'admin_page_output'), 
            plugins_url( 'wp-idangerous-swiper/img/swiper-icon.png' ));
}

public function admin_page_output() {
  echo "Hello iDangerous Swiper";
}
```

I am calling this in my classes constructor:

```
public function __construct() {
     add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'register_wpidSwiper_menu_page' ) );
}
```

My menu item appears in the side menu, with my custom icon, but when I click to go to the page the page displays the error I mentioned above instead of the string I echo in my **admin_page_output()** method.

Anyone know where this is going wrong for me?

Thanks!
Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `$this` in **static** context.

```
public static function
```

Inside a static function, `$this` does not exist.  Try getting rid of `static`, I'm not really a wordpress person but my guess is that will fix it.

Comment: Ah, duh. was not thinking about that. That did the trick thnx. Strange that the function ran at all.